# How do we restrict access to certain Account, contact and opportunity records to certain users

Tags: permissions, sharing, permission-sets

I have a few `Accounts, Contacts, Opportunities` and a custom object to be accessible only to a group of users. All other `Accounts/Opps/Contacts/Custom Objects` are to be accessible by all users.

The OWD is currently public

Comment: OWD public means you can't take away read privileges. Switching from OWD Public to Private can be a huge undertaking involving lots of regression testing

Answer (score 0):

With standard detail page you can't restrict user to access specific account so as a solution you can follow below steps.

1. Create one checkPermission visualforce page.
2. Inside action method put your logic to check whether that group of users has access to that account or not. You can store such users or account inside custom metadata or custom setting.
3. If group of users has permission redirect them to standard detail page else redirect them to another noPermission visualforce page.

Comment: mmm.. really we have only a apex solution? i know there is something with criteria based sharing

Comment: your OWD is public in that case you will not get sharing option

Comment: We could change it to private but not sure of the implications of it

Comment: You can use sharing rules to grant wider access to data. You cannot restrict access below your organization-wide default levels.

Comment: @Prady Please go through this documentation https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_rule_considerations.htm&language=en

Comment: Himanshu -- this sort of works but won't prevent access via reports or list views

Comment: @cropredy yah I agree. Best option is to go for OWD private and sharing rules. for sure. It entirely depends on use case.